# Getting ERROR at line 1: ORA-01722: invalid number ORA-06512: at line 88 while executing my piece of code

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
    cycCode                                 NUMBER; --3;
    cycInstance                             NUMBER;
    cycYear                                 NUMBER;
    cycStartDate                            VARCHAR2(8);
    cycEndDate                              VARCHAR2(8);
    custKey                                 NUMBER;
    subNo                                   NUMBER;
    custNo                                  NUMBER;
    pcn                                     NUMBER;
    offr                                    NUMBER;
    ofrItm                                  NUMBER;
    ofrInst                                 NUMBER;
    pkgCode                                 VARCHAR2(50);
    activitySeq                             NUMBER;
    rcEffDt                                 DATE;
    rcExptDt                                DATE;
    actvityDt                               DATE;
    noOfDis                                 NUMBER;
    rcRateSeq                               NUMBER;

    CURSOR pop_1  IS
        SELECT rc.customer_key,
               rc.service_receiver_id,
               rc.receiver_customer,
               rc.pay_channel_no,
               getdyna(rc.dynamic_attributes, '#Packaging code'),
               rc.offer,
               rc.offer_item,
               rc.offer_instance,
               rc.insert_activity_seq,
               rc.effective_date,
               rc.expiration_date,
               TRUNC(act.activity_date)
          FROM bl1_rc_rates rc, bl1_activity_history act
         WHERE     rc.cycle_code = cycCode
               AND rc.effective_date - 1 <= TO_DATE(cycEndDate, 'ddmmyyyy')
               AND NVL(rc.expiration_date, TO_DATE(cycStartDate, 'ddmmyyyy')) + 1 >= TO_DATE(cycStartDate, 'ddmmyyyy')
               AND rc.amount > 0
               AND NVL(rc.expiration_date, TO_DATE('31124700', 'ddmmyyyy')) >= rc.effective_date --and rc.receiver_customer=648934805 and rc.charge_code='HS_R_R_ER_WXB6S'
               AND rc.insert_activity_seq = act.activity_seq
               AND rc.effective_date = TRUNC(act.activity_date) + 1 --and rc.customer_key=28
               AND getdyna(rc.dynamic_attributes, 'Product offer ID') IN (SELECT product_offer_id
                                                                            FROM bl9_product_offer
                                                                           WHERE subscriber_type = 'BS');


    CURSOR pop_2  IS
        SELECT CASE WHEN rc1.application_id = 'DSCRC ' THEN rc1.rc_rate_seq_no ELSE rc2.rc_rate_seq_no END AS rc_rate_seq_no
          --,rc1.charge_code, rc1.amount, rc2.charge_code, rc2.amount, rc1.effective_date, rc1.expiration_date, rc2.effective_date, rc2.expiration_date
          FROM bl1_rc_rates rc1, bl1_rc_rates rc2
         WHERE     rc1.customer_key = custKey
               AND rc1.service_receiver_id = subNo
               AND rc1.service_receiver_type = 'S'
               AND rc1.receiver_customer = custNo
               AND rc1.pay_channel_no = pcn
               AND NVL(rc1.expiration_date, TO_DATE('31124700', 'ddmmyyyy')) >= rc1.effective_date
               AND rc1.amount < 0
               AND rc1.effective_date - 1 <= TO_DATE(cycEndDate, 'ddmmyyyy')
               AND NVL(rc1.expiration_date, TO_DATE(cycStartDate, 'ddmmyyyy')) + 1 >= TO_DATE(cycStartDate, 'ddmmyyyy')
               AND getdyna(rc1.dynamic_attributes, 'Base offer id') = offr
               AND getdyna(rc1.dynamic_attributes, 'Base offer item id') = ofrItm
               AND getdyna(rc1.dynamic_attributes, 'Base offer instance id') = ofrInst
               AND rc1.effective_date >= actvityDt
               AND rc2.customer_key = rc1.customer_key
               AND rc2.service_receiver_id = rc1.service_receiver_id
               AND rc2.service_receiver_type = 'S'
               AND rc2.receiver_customer = rc1.receiver_customer
               AND rc2.pay_channel_no = rc1.pay_channel_no
               AND NVL(rc2.expiration_date, TO_DATE('31124700', 'ddmmyyyy')) >= rc2.effective_date
               AND rc2.amount < 0
               AND rc2.effective_date - 1 <= TO_DATE(cycEndDate, 'ddmmyyyy')
               AND NVL(rc2.expiration_date, TO_DATE(cycStartDate, 'ddmmyyyy')) + 1 >= TO_DATE(cycStartDate, 'ddmmyyyy')
               AND getdyna(rc2.dynamic_attributes, 'Base offer id') = getdyna(rc1.dynamic_attributes, 'Base offer id')
               AND getdyna(rc2.dynamic_attributes, 'Base offer item id') = getdyna(rc1.dynamic_attributes, 'Base offer item id')
               AND getdyna(rc2.dynamic_attributes, 'Base offer instance id') = getdyna(rc1.dynamic_attributes, 'Base offer instance id')
               AND rc2.effective_date >= actvityDt
               AND rc1.insert_activity_seq = rc2.insert_activity_seq
               AND rc1.effective_date <= rc2.effective_date
               AND (   rc1.application_id = 'DSCRC '
                    OR rc2.application_id = 'DSCRC ')
               AND rc1.effective_date <= NVL(rc2.expiration_date, TO_DATE('31124700', 'ddmmyyyy'))
               AND NVL(rc1.expiration_date, TO_DATE('31124700', 'ddmmyyyy')) >= rc2.effective_date
               AND getdyna(rc1.dynamic_attributes, '#Packaging code') = getdyna(rc2.dynamic_attributes, '#Packaging code')
               AND getdyna(rc1.dynamic_attributes, '#Savings code') = getdyna(rc2.dynamic_attributes, '#Savings code')
               AND rc1.rc_rate_seq_no <> rc2.rc_rate_seq_no;

    CURSOR pop_3  IS
        SELECT rc.rc_rate_seq_no
          FROM bl1_rc_rates rc
         WHERE     rc.customer_key = custKey
               AND rc.service_receiver_id = subNo
               AND rc.service_receiver_type = 'S'
               AND rc.receiver_customer = custNo
               AND rc.expiration_date IS NOT NULL
               AND rc.pay_channel_no = pcn
               AND NVL(rc.expiration_date, TO_DATE('31124700', 'ddmmyyyy')) >= rc.effective_date
               AND rc.amount < 0
               AND rc.effective_date - 1 <= TO_DATE(cycEndDate, 'ddmmyyyy')
               AND NVL(rc.expiration_date, TO_DATE(cycStartDate, 'ddmmyyyy')) + 1 >= TO_DATE(cycStartDate, 'ddmmyyyy')
               AND getdyna(rc.dynamic_attributes, 'Base offer id') = offr
               AND getdyna(rc.dynamic_attributes, 'Base offer item id') = ofrItm
               AND getdyna(rc.dynamic_attributes, 'Base offer instance id') = ofrInst
               AND NVL(rc.expiration_date, TO_DATE('31124700', 'ddmmyyyy')) > rcExptDt
               AND NOT EXISTS
                       (SELECT 1
                          FROM bl1_rc_rates base
                         WHERE     base.customer_key = rc.customer_key
                               AND base.service_receiver_id = rc.service_receiver_id
                               AND base.service_receiver_type = rc.service_receiver_type
                               AND base.receiver_customer = rc.receiver_customer
                               AND base.pay_channel_no = rc.pay_channel_no
                               AND base.amount > 0
                               AND base.offer = offr
                               AND base.offer_item = ofrItm
                               AND base.offer_instance = ofrInst
                               AND base.effective_date <= rc.effective_date
                               AND NVL(base.expiration_date, TO_DATE('31124700', 'ddmmyyyy')) >= NVL(rc.expiration_date, TO_DATE('31124700', 'ddmmyyyy')));

    CURSOR pop_new  IS
        SELECT cycle_code,
               cycle_instance,
               cycle_year
          FROM bl1_cycle_control
         WHERE     start_date = TRUNC(SYSDATE - 30)
               AND end_date = TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1)
               AND cycle_code NOT IN (77,
                                      36,
                                      88,
                                      29);
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(10000000);

    OPEN pop_new;

    LOOP
        FETCH pop_new
            INTO cycCode,
                 cycInstance,
                 cycYear;

        EXIT WHEN pop_new%NOTFOUND;

        SELECT TO_CHAR(start_date, 'ddmmyyyy'), TO_CHAR(end_date, 'ddmmyyyy')
          INTO cycStartDate, cycEndDate
          FROM bl1_cycle_control
         WHERE     cycle_code = cycCode
               AND cycle_instance = cycInstance
               AND cycle_year = cycYear;

        OPEN pop_1;

        LOOP
            FETCH pop_1
                INTO custKey,
                     subNo,
                     custNo,
                     pcn,
                     pkgCode,
                     offr,
                     ofrItm,
                     ofrInst,
                     activitySeq,
                     rcEffDt,
                     rcExptDt,
                     actvityDt;

            EXIT WHEN pop_1%NOTFOUND;
            noOfDis    := 0;

            --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Record: '||custKey||','||subNo||','||custNo||','||pcn||','||offr||','||ofrItm||','||ofrInst||','||activitySeq||','||rcEffDt||','||actvityDt);

            SELECT COUNT(1)
              INTO noOfDis
              FROM bl1_rc_rates rc
             WHERE     rc.customer_key = custKey
                   AND rc.service_receiver_id = subNo
                   AND rc.service_receiver_type = 'S'
                   AND rc.receiver_customer = custNo
                   AND rc.pay_channel_no = pcn
                   AND rc.effective_date = rcEffDt - 1
                   AND NVL(rc.expiration_date, TO_DATE('31124700', 'ddmmyyyy')) >= rc.effective_date
                   AND rc.amount < 0
                   AND rc.effective_date - 1 <= TO_DATE(cycEndDate, 'ddmmyyyy')
                   AND NVL(rc.expiration_date, TO_DATE(cycStartDate, 'ddmmyyyy')) + 1 >= TO_DATE(cycStartDate, 'ddmmyyyy')
                   AND NVL(rc.expiration_date, TO_DATE('31124700', 'ddmmyyyy')) >= rc.effective_date
                   AND getdyna(rc.dynamic_attributes, 'Base offer id') = offr
                   AND getdyna(rc.dynamic_attributes, 'Base offer item id') = ofrItm
                   AND getdyna(rc.dynamic_attributes, 'Base offer instance id') = ofrInst;


            IF (noOfDis > 0)
            THEN
                UPDATE bl1_rc_rates rc
                   SET effective_date     = TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(rcEffDt - 1, 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'dd-mm-yyyy'),
                       sys_update_date    = SYSDATE,
                       operator_id        = '90',
                       application_id     = 'BRC'
                 WHERE     rc.customer_key = 'custKey'
                       AND rc.service_receiver_type = 'S'
                       AND rc.service_receiver_id = 'subNo'
                       AND rc.receiver_customer = 'custNo'
                       AND rc.pay_channel_no = 'pcn'
                       AND rc.offer = 'offr'
                       AND rc.offer_item = 'ofrItm'
                       AND rc.offer_instance = 'ofrInst'
                       AND rc.effective_date = TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(rcEffDt, 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'dd-mm-yyyy')
                       AND getdyna(rc.dynamic_attributes, '#Packaging code') = 'pkgCode'
                       AND operator_id <> '90';
            END IF;

            OPEN pop_2;

            LOOP
                FETCH pop_2 INTO rcRateSeq;

                EXIT WHEN pop_2%NOTFOUND;

                UPDATE bl1_rc_rates rc
                   SET rc.expiration_date    = rc.effective_date - 1,
                       operator_id           = '90',
                       application_id        = 'BDC'
                 WHERE     rc.customer_key = 'custKey'
                       AND rc.rc_rate_seq_no = 'rcRateSeq'
                       AND rc.operator_id <> '90';
            END LOOP;

            CLOSE pop_2;

            OPEN pop_3;

            LOOP
                FETCH pop_3 INTO rcRateSeq;

                EXIT WHEN pop_3%NOTFOUND;

                UPDATE bl1_rc_rates rc
                   SET rc.expiration_date    = TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(rcExptDt, 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'dd-mm-yyyy'),
                       operator_id           = '90',
                       application_id        = 'ORDC'
                 WHERE     rc.customer_key = 'custKey'
                       AND rc.rc_rate_seq_no = 'rcRateSeq'
                       AND rc.operator_id <> '90';
            END LOOP;

            CLOSE pop_3;
        END LOOP;

        CLOSE pop_1;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE pop_new;
END;
/
```

Comment: Here you find  something on [ask] and how to build a [mcve] that can be useful to improve your question. For example, say someone wants to help you, no matter your code is not well formatted and very long for a question, without knowing your tables, it's impossible to know if, say, you are handling a date as a number, a char as a date and so on...

Comment: Line 88 points to the `pop_3` cursor, so try to sun that query on its own, putting in the values you expect (with the right data types) from the PL/SQL variables. Somewhere you are doing an implicit conversion from a string to a number, but we can't see your tables or data, or what the function you are calling is doing or returning. You need to do some basic debugging of that query.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're implicitly casting and doing date manipulation.

I'm guessing that bl1_rc_rates.effective_date is not truly a date column, but a varchar2, or number(8).

If you run the query

```
select bc.effective_date, bc.effective_date - 1
from bl1_rc_rates bc;
```

Does it run without error?

Find the column with the bad data and fix it, and your procedure will work again. You could also do some checking on data entry that what you're putting in there are valid dates.

In the future, I would suggest trying to takes parts out of the procedure and run them on your own to narrow down the error. IN this case it gives you the line number that should set you well on your way.